# Sending secret/personal message to particular cc in outlook

Tags: email, outlook-addin

How can I send personal message to particular CC recipient(s) in outlook using C# so that other CC or or BCC or TO recipients can't able to view this personal message?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to send a message to that recipient only.

Comment: Can I attach that personal message as ATTACHMENT and then send it only to that particular CC recipient?

Comment: Sure, but you will need to create a *separate* email for each recipient. Again, if you create a message with multiple recipients, all recipients will receive the same message (attachments and all). If you need different messages for different recipients, you need to create different messages and send them separately.