# send personal message as attachment and send it to particular cc so that other CC/TO/BCC cannot see that attachment

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-addin

How can I attach a personal message as ATTACHMENT in outlook and then send it only to that particular CC recipient using C# ?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear but I hope these information will help you....

Please find the below code to send an email to the CC recepient with attachment

```
var oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
var oMsg = (MailItem) oApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

Recipients oRecips = oMsg.Recipients;

List<string> sCCRecipsList = new List<string>();

sCCRecipsList.Add("CCRecipient1");
sCCRecipsList.Add("CCRecipient2");
sCCRecipsList.Add("CCRecipient3");

Recipients oRecips = oMsg.Recipients;

foreach (string t in sCCRecipsList)
{
    Recipient oCCRecip = oRecips.Add(t);
    oCCRecip.Type = (int) OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
    oCCRecip.Resolve();
}

oMsg.Attachments.Add(@"C:\\fileName.txt", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);

oMsg.HTMLBody = "Test Body";
oMsg.Subject = "Test Subject";
oMsg.Send();
```

CC list adding to the mail. Please see the below code

```
foreach (string t in sCCRecipsList)
{
    Recipient oCCRecip = oRecips.Add(t);
    oCCRecip.Type = (int) OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
    oCCRecip.Resolve();
}
```

Attaching txt file to the mail, Please see the below code

```
oMsg.Attachments.Add(@"C:\\fileName.txt", iAttachType, iPosition, sDisplayName);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247611/sending-secret-personal-message-to-particular-cc-in-outlook